# why the elements of the list is not in the same structure?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have this queryset

```
ranges = AgeRange.objects.all().order_by("id")
ranges_list = [{item.id,  item.frm_to } for item in ranges]
```

and I got this result:

```
[{1, '1-6'}, {2, '1-18'}, {3, '1-40'}, {'40-60', 4}, {5, '60-100'}]
```

I cannot figure out why the elements of 4th item **{'40-60', 4}** is reversed. How can ensure that the id comes left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curly braces are used to declare sets, and sets are unordered. It's coincidence that it only affects one of your items.

The simplest fix would be to use parentheses to create tuples instead of sets, a better fix would be to use a `values_list` query in the first place if you truly only need those two fields:

```
ranges_list = [(item.id, item.frm_to) for item in ranges]
```

or:

```
ranges_list = AgeRange.objects.all().order_by("id").values_list("id", "frm_to")
```

In that last case, you don't need the `ranges` query.
It'll return an iterable queryset result rather than a list - if you truly need a list immediately, just call the `list()` constructor on it:

```
ranges_list = list(AgeRangeobjects.all().order_by("id").values_list("id", "frm_to"))
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [Python doc](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)

> A `set` object is an ***"unordered"*** collection of distinct hashable objects.

The element **`{2, '1-18'}`** is a ***Python `set`*** object, which doesn't have any ***order***

You can check the type of the element by, **`print(type({2, '1-18'}))`** which will print `set`, obviously.

To ensure, id become first, use ***tuple*** instead of *set*

```
ranges_list = [(item.id, item.frm_to) for item in ranges]
```